# Invalid use of useEffect in React function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having an issue with calling useEffect from this function.  I haven't been using React that long so I may have some glaring issues but this is taking up too much time.

**My function is as follows:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export function Sessions() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://localhost:7126/api/`)
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(
                        `This is an HTTP error: The status is ${response.status}`
                    );
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((actualData) => {
                setData(actualData);
                setError(null);
                setCount(actualData.length);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
    }, []);


    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Stream Request: {count} records</h1>
            {loading && <div>A moment please...</div>}
            {error && (
                <div>{`There is a problem fetching the post data - ${error}`}</div>
            )}
            <ul>
                {data &&
                    data.map(({ StreamId, EntryTime }) => (
                        <li key={StreamId}>
                            <h3>{EntryTime}</h3>
                        </li>
                    ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**The error i'm receiving is**

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

#1)I have updated React and React-Dom they were both up to date.
#2) ? I don't think I am?

#3) I have verified this using npm ls react and my output is as follows:

```
+-- react-dom@18.2.0
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- react-router-dom@6.4.3
| +-- react-router@6.4.3
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- react@18.2.0
`-- reactstrap@9.1.5
  +-- react-popper@2.3.0
  | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
  +-- react-transition-group@4.4.5
  | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
  `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
```

All seem to be deduped?
Please help, none of the other questions have helped my issue such as :[Invalid Hook Call but not really](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64730868/8767516)

**Edit**
I use Sessions via App.js & AppRoutes.js
App.js:

```
import "./stylesheet.css";
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppRoutes from './AppRoutes';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';


export default class App extends Component {
    static displayName = App.name;

    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <Routes>
                    {AppRoutes.map((route, index) => {
                        const { element, ...rest } = route;
                        return <Route key={index} {...rest} element={element} />;
                    })}
                </Routes>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}
```

AppRoutes.js:

```
import { Sessions } from "./components/Sessions";
import { Messages } from "./components/Messages";
import { Home } from "./components/Home";

const AppRoutes = [
  {
    index: true,
    element: <Home />
  },
  {
    path: '/sessions',
    element: <Sessions />
  },
  {
    path: '/messages',
    element: <Messages />
  }
];

export default AppRoutes;
```

Comment: Please show how do you use `Sessions`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I edited above to show, not sure if Sessions should remain a function or a class..? thank u

Comment: The minimal code seems to be working in a codesandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-rhodes-kjpnck?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Should i switch this to a class with a constructor{}?  I'm still confused why this doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably not the solution but maybe it could give you some ideas. As you are not `await`ing the call properly inside your `useEffect()`, it could be causing issues for your code and errors that are not that descriptive.

Here are some suggestions:

- use the `async`/`await` API instead of the `.then()`/`.catch()` from Promises.
- create an internal function for your asynchronous function and call it inside the `useEffect()` hook after defining it. In general (from my experience), `async` calls at "top-level" `useEffect()` hook trigger some warnings.

As a possible solution, this is the code I suggest you change and start from:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const internalFetch = async () => {
    try {
      const actualData = await fetch(`https://localhost:7126/api/`)
      setData(actualData);
      setError(null);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  }

  internalFetch();
}, []);
```

You could use `data.length` directly instead of creating a state for `count`.

Again: I don't know if this will fix your issue but it could give you another error that could be more descriptive. And, also as a final suggestion, you could use a lib for fetching data such as `react-query`, that isolates and cache your data for you.

Comment: This gives me an 'unexpected token' error on the last line of ```}, []);```

Comment: You probably didn't closed the `}` or closed more `}`s than necessary.